# События при перетаскивании вершин ломаной над другими объектами

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте. 
Каким образом можно отследить событие появления вершины ломаной линии при ее редактировании (или рисовании) над (или под) другим объектом карты, например, ранее поставленной меткой? Или поймать событие конца перетаскивания вершины ломаной над меткой?

Пробовал отследить события mouseenter и mouseleave, но это не выходит. Все получается, разумеется, на уже нарисованных объектах, а вот в процессе отрисовки - нет.

Еще вопрос - почему метки на карте всегда заслоняют ломаные линии? Можно ли это изменить?

Answer (score 0):

У редактора геометрий есть свой доступный набор событий. Они описаны [в документации.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometryEditor.LineString-docpage/?from=SO#events-summary)
Можно отслеживать конец перетаскивания вершины через событие `vertexdragend` и после определять, попала ли вершина под другой объект.